# How to store hard boiled eggs that are peeled so to avoid moisture build up?

Tags: eggs, breakfast, hard-boiled-eggs

On the weekend I usually make 10 hard boiled eggs and peel them so I can eat 2 every morning during the work week. It's a big time saver in the morning, but when I store them in a plastic container in the refrigerator, a ton of moisture accumulates. I've tried putting a napkin in the container to soak up any water that appears but it doesn't help much. Does anyone know how you should store hard boiled eggs that are peeled? Is peeling them going to reduce how long they stay good? And does anyone know how long peeled and unpeeled eggs should stay good for?

In case anyone is wondering. I make the eggs by putting them in a pot with water, then bring it to a rolling boil, remove from heat, cover the pot and let it sit for 12 minutes. I then crack the eggs and dip them in water to remove any small pieces of shells, and then finally dry them.

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I have never tried this, but what you could do is wrap each egg in two paper towels. You could also store them on a plate instead of in a container, but I think they will dry out. You could also try wrapping each egg tightly in plastic foil, but that might have the opposite result, I don't know. Lastly, it may help if you let the eggs cool off with the container lid open until they are at fridge temperature, to avoid condensation inside the container.

Comment: One wonders where the moisture is coming from - presumably from the egg itself, which means it's drying out. I do what SAJ14SAJ suggests, and leave them in the shell. Seems fine. But egg shells are permeable, so they might be dehydrating there to, perhaps.

Answer (score 18):

This is probably not what you want to hear on any front, but it is best to store your eggs in their shell.  Their original carton provides an ideal container.

If you do want to store them peeled, the standard way to do it is refrigerated in a bowl of water (changed daily).    Of course, you will then have to dry the egg before eating it the wetness bothers you.  This method is also used with poached eggs.

Lastly, you can do what you are already doing, and store them with some towels, but they will probably express some water.

---

The eggs should be good for about one week, unpeeled.  The [Egg Board](http://www.incredibleegg.org/recipes/recipe/basic-hard-boiled-eggs) recommends they be eaten the same day they are peeled, but [other sources](http://www.eatbydate.com/hard-boiled-eggs-shelf-life-expiration-date/) indicate up to about 5 days.

See also:

- [Still Tasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17147)
- [Eat By Date](http://www.eatbydate.com/hard-boiled-eggs-shelf-life-expiration-date/)

Comment: wow thanks for the in depth reply. I'll probably move to not peeling them until I eat them since they'll stay longer.

Answer (score 7):

I work at a restaurant and we keep peeled eggs (for salads) in a covered container and cover them with fresh water. Ours don't usually last longer than 2 days or so (before we run out and have to make more), but we are able to keep them for up to a week, and they taste just as fresh on day 7 as on day 1, so long as you remember to change the water out daily. They may stay fresh for longer, but we don't keep any prepared foods for longer than 7 days, and if I wouldn't feed it to my customers after 7 days I certainly wouldn't feed it to myself.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I am very interested in trying the baking soda method and I will this weekend. I do the same thing as David to save time during my busy week by cooking them up on the weekend and peeling them ready to eat. As for storage I let them cool down fully, dry them and  place them in a container and put them in the fridge. The next day I drain out any liquid then put a splash of white vinegar in and lightly shake them around. They are good like that for 4 or 5 days. If you haven't gone through them by then give them a rinse with water and put a fresh splash of vinegar. I think the vinegar works as a preservative killing off the nasties that may form in that liquid that appears. Works for me as long as you don't mind the slight taste a vinegar.

Comment: Wow, never thought of using vinegar. Thanks for the idea! Does the vinegar leave a weird taste?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the shelling to a second and literally blow the eggs out of the shells if you add a couple of spoons of baking soda to the water. They should make it through the week. Some say boiled eggs last for a very long time in their shell.  Though not sure about the modern washed eggs and would recommend staying within the 5-day thing.

Checkout this [video by Tim Ferris](http://youtu.be/PN2gYHJNT3Y) and a party trick.

Comment: Have you tried Tim Ferris' method and does it work? It seems almost too good to be true. Also, does the baking soda change the taste at all?

Comment: @David I haven't tried it, but it works.  Tim Ferris is a famous author/hacker and everything else of his I've tried, works (I also know the science behind it is sound).  The baking soda _might_ alter the taste.  You may be able to add much less with no taste difference and still have no shrapnel when peeling the egg 5 days later.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm definitely going to try it out next week when I make them. When you say Ferris' methods work, are you talking about both the 4 hour workweek and 4 hour chef?

Comment: @David 4-hr body is his real domain.  4-hr chef is also well grounded (in which he apologizes for the above video as a culinary crime).  He used to prepare his eggs that way before he became a foodie (I wouldn't call him a chef yet).  He also has a slow-carb breakfast video.

Comment: Just watched Tim Ferriss' method for "peeling eggs without peeling". this may work for your own egg consumption but I care not to eat eggs (say deviled eggs served at a party) that someone else has blown on. YUK!

Answer (score 0):

Peeling them IS THE TIME SAVER .. So keeping them in water is the best way and having to dry them ( with a paper towel or how ever) is what I have to do is not that te consuming .. It is peeling them ... I do this weekly .... Hard boil them keep them in water and every morning grab 2 rinse for 3 seconds then dry them off for 3 seconds .. Sprinkle salt and pepper on them  and eat .. This whole prices only takes me under 1 minute usually 30 second ... So  I can in fact say keeping in water is a quick way to eat eggs and keeps them tasting the freshest and in water I know they are protected from everything .. Drying out germs ... Whatever .. Hope this helps .... Sometimes I bring to work .. I invested in a lock tight container that cost under a few dollars and I can keep them in water and put the container in a bag with all my important papers and not worry about the container opening and water COMMING out ... Of if you don't have one use tape or rubber bands then wrapp up with plastic wrap or tin foil or zip lock bag ... I do Love the lock lids ... They have to have the removable rubber seal to ensure a tight leakproof seal ... Hope this helps ... I have also been a chef for 30 plus years and have been to many food management training schools .. And also family owned restaurants plus managed a few . So any questions u can find me on FB or

Comment: What makes you think putting the eggs in water will protect it from germs?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the eggs individually after you peel them. I use Glad Press-N-Seal. Lay a sheet of it over an ice cube tray, set the eggs in the hollows, then layer on a second, longer sheet of wrap, making the top wrap contact the bottom one between each egg. Remove from ice cube tray and press out the air from around each egg as you tighten the wrap. You can leave them all together, or cut them apart into individuak airtight little packages.