# How long can boiled eggs be stored in the fridge?

Tags: eggs, storage-lifetime, hard-boiled-eggs

I boiled some eggs one week ago and forgot to eat them, so they stayed in the fridge. How long will they stay consumable in there?

Comment: See also:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14287/are-refrigerated-hard-boild-eggs-really-unsafe-after-a-week

Comment: And also:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35920/how-to-store-hard-boiled-eggs-that-are-peeled-so-to-avoid-moisture-build-up

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The USDA recommends storing hard boiled eggs, whether peeled or not, for 1 week. I personally have kept & eaten them after 2-3 weeks. I have also cracked one open that was no longer edible & believe me - You will know when that happens! The egg will will smell rotten & you will have no question as to whether or not to eat it!
Some additional Info on storing eggs:

Eggs should be stored in a refrigerator at about 40 degrees F, mainly to reduce the chances that any bacteria on the shell will multiply and cause a risk of illness.

Buy refrigerated eggs and store them in the refrigerator as soon as your get home. However, even under refrigeration, eggs slowly lose carbon dioxide, which enlarges the size of the air cell and causes the yolk to flatten and the white to spread.

```
                  **Storage Times**
```

- Fresh Egg - Refrigerated raw shell eggs will keep without significant quality loss for about 4 -  5 weeks beyond the "sell by" date or about 3 weeks after you bring them home.
- Fresh egg whites - 2 to 4 days
- Fresh egg yolks (unbroken and covered with water) - 2 to 4 days
- Deviled eggs - 2 to 3 days
- Leftover egg dishes - 3 to 4 days